# What is the method to solve or approximately solve an optimization with zero-norm restriction?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The zero norm of a vector ${\bf x}\in \Bbb R^n$ is the number of non-zero values in $\bf x$, denoted by $\|{\bf x} \|_0$ (zero norm is not exactly a norm, it does not satisfy the scaling property, i.e. ${\left\| {\lambda {\mathbf{x}}} \right\|_0} = {\left\| {\mathbf{x}} \right\|_0}$ rather than "${\left\| {\lambda {\mathbf{x}}} \right\|_0} = |\lambda |{\left\| {\mathbf{x}} \right\|_0}$" for $\lambda \neq 0$). For a simple example, we might want to optimize

> ${\min _{{\mathbf{x}} \in {\mathbb{R}^n}}}{\left\| {{\mathbf{Ax}} - {\mathbf{y}}} \right\|_2}$ s.t. ${\left\| {\mathbf{x}} \right\|_0} < 2$, where ${\mathbf{A}} \in {\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}},{\mathbf{y}} \in {\mathbb{R}^m}$ are given

For another more complicated example,

> ${\min _{\mathbf{P}\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}}}{\left\| {{{\mathbf{P}}^{\text{T}}}{\mathbf{AP}} - {\mathbf{B}}} \right\|_{\text{F}}}$ s.t. ${\left\| {{\mathbf{P}}(i,)} \right\|_0} \leqslant 2$ for every $i=1,...,n$. ${\mathbf{A}},{\mathbf{B}} \in {\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}$ are given.

**Such zero norm restriction frequently appears in optimization models with sparsity assumption**. What is the method to solve such problem? Any help of reference is very much appreciated!

---

I googled several papers, but they are all about optimizing the zero norm itself, for example [Use of the zero-norm with linear models and kernel methods](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/weston03a/weston03a.pdf), and [A Note on the Complexity of Lp Minimization](http://web.stanford.edu/~yyye/lpmin_v14.pdf), and [$\cal l_0$-norm Minimization for Basis Selection](http://dsp.ucsd.edu/~dwipf/paper819.pdf) etc.

Comment: If you want to solve $\min f(x)$ subject to $g(x)\le g_0$, you can instead solve $\min g(x)$ subject to $f(x)\le f_0$ and use bisection to find the smallest $f_0$ for which the optimum satisfies $g(x)\le g_0$.